# Swift Dictionary Multiple Key Value Pairs - Iteration

Tags: swift, dictionary, iteration

In Swift I want to make an array of dictionaries (with multiple key value pairs) and then iterate over each element

Below is the expected output of a possible dictionary. Not sure how to declare and intitialize it (somewhat similar to array of hashes in Ruby)

```
 dictionary = [{id: 1, name: "Apple", category: "Fruit"}, {id: 2, name: "Bee", category: "Insect"}]
```

I know how to make an array of dictionary with one key value pair.
For example:

```
 var airports: [String: String] = ["YYZ": "Toronto Pearson", "DUB": "Dublin"]
```

Comment: Your `airports` variable is not an array of dictionaries, just a dictionary. However if you declare it like `var airports: [[String: String]] = [["YYZ": "Toronto Pearson", "DUB": "Dublin"]]`, it would be, just pay attention to the braces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to declare an array of dictionary, use this:

```
var arrayOfDictionary: [[String : AnyObject]]  = [["id" :1, "name": "Apple", "category" : "Fruit"],["id" :2, "name": "Microsoft", "category" : "Juice"]]
```

I see that in your dictionary, you mix number with string, so it's better use AnyObject instead of String for data type in dictionary.
If after this code, you do not have to modify the content of this array, declare it as 'let', otherwise, use 'var'

Update: to initialize within a loop:

```
//create empty array
var emptyArrayOfDictionary = [[String : AnyObject]]()
for x in 2...3 {  //... mean the loop includes last value => x = 2,3
    //add new dictionary for each loop
    emptyArrayOfDictionary.append(["number" : x , "square" : x*x ])
}
//your new array must contain: [["number": 2, "square": 4], ["number": 3, "square": 9]]
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense.  How can I initialize within a for loop, for example if I want: dictionary:[[String: AnyObject]] =[ ["number": 2, "square": 4],["number: 3, "square": 9]]

the below did not work

var dictionary: [[String: AnyObject]]

for x in 2...3 {
var new = ["number" : x, "square": x*x]
somehow append new to dictionary
}

Answer (score 1):

```
let dic_1: [String: Int] = ["one": 1, "two": 2]
let dic_2: [String: Int] = ["a": 1, "b": 2]
let list_1 = [dic_1, dic_2]

// or in one step:
let list_2: [[String: Int]] = [["one": 1, "two": 2], ["a": 1, "b": 2]]

for d in list_1 { // or list_2
    print(d)
}
```

which results in

> ["one": 1, "two": 2]
>
> ["b": 2, "a": 1]

Answer (score 1):

```
let airports: [[String: String]] = [["YYZ": "Toronto Pearson", "DUB": "Dublin"]]

for airport in airports {
    print(airport["YYZ"])
}
```